# How do you rotate a given image?

Tags: c++, image, function, class, header-files

supposing the image is i object file "a", I have created another object file called b to rotate the image. I was giving (j,i) of a to (i,j) of b, but my code isn't working because am not properly using that function called operator, I have "//" the things I have tried, but I kept getting error, what should I do?
rgbapixels is a pixel class, just like png is an image class;

in PNG.h, we now have the function defined as;

```
#include <iostream>
#include "rgbapixel.h"
class PNG
{
public:
RGBAPixel * operator()(size_t x, size_t y);
/**
* Const pixel access operator. Const version of the previous
* operator(). Does not allow the image to be changed via the
* pointer.
* @param x X-coordinate for the pixel pointer to be grabbed from.
* @param y Y-cooridnate for the pixel pointer to be grabbed from.
* @return A pointer to the pixel at the given coordinates (can't
*      change the pixel through this pointer).
*/
size_t width() const;   // returns width
size_t width() const;
private:
// storage
size_t _width;
size_t _height;
RGBAPixel * _pixels;
};
```

The functions were implemented for us in png.cpp. So, in main.cpp, I have my code to use them;

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

#include "rgbapixel.h"
#include "png.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
cout << "me..........." << endl;
PNG a("I have put the image in "a" here");
PNG b;
for(size_t i = 0; i < a.width(); i++)
{
for(size_t j = 0; j <a.height(); j++)
{
// *b(i, j) = *a(j, i);                               erata
// b(i,j) = RGBAPixel * operator()(size_t x, size_t y);
//  b(i, j) = operator()(i, j);              
//b(i,j) = *operator(i,j);
//b(j,i) = a*operator(i,j);
//b(j,i) = a.operator(i,j);
//b(j, i) = a.*operator(i,j);
}
}
return 0;
}
```

I am getting errors with using the function, I can't tell what's wrong. So, I don't know whether my alogarithm will get the image rotated

some errors;

```
[jonathan2@linux-a1 lab_intro]$ make
clang++ -std=c++1y -stdlib=libc++ -c -g -O0 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.cpp
main.cpp:24:29: error: expected ')'
b(i,j) = *operator(i,j);
                    ^
main.cpp:24:28: note: to match this '('
b(i,j) = *operator(i,j);
                   ^
main.cpp:24:20: error: use of undeclared 'operator()'
b(i,j) = *operator(i,j);
           ^
2 errors generated.
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `()` operator gets used when the instance of the class with this operator gets invoked as a function call.

So, with your `PNG` class, and two instances of it called `a` and `b`, their `()` operator would get simply invoked as:

```
a(i, j)
```

or

```
b(i, j)
```

Since your `()` operator returns a `RGBAPixel *`, the end result of such a pseudo-function call is a pointer, that, I presume, should be dereferenced.

The first commented out line of code in your example:

```
// *b(i, j) = *a(j, i);
```

This looks to me like the correct usage of your `()` operator. I don't see any issues with compiling that.

Comment: But it fails, it gives me the error;                                clang++ -std=c++1y -stdlib=libc++ -c -g -O0 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.cpp
    main.cpp:21:62: error: use of undeclared identifier 'erata'
          *b(i, j) = *a(j, i);                               erata
                                                             ^
    1 error generated.
    make: *** [main.o] Error 1

Comment: Your error message clearly references 'erata', whatever that is. The error message does not appear to have anything to do with the assignment statement. Helpful tip: always read an error message at least three times, before giving up and asking someone else for help. Especially clang's error messages, which have a reputation for their clarity and usefulness.

Comment: It works, but then for some reason, when I output the image in "b", its empty, and it shows that no pixels were copied. th given warnings;.......[EasyPNG]: Warning: attempted to access non-existent pixel (511, 383);
            Truncating request to fit in the range [0,0] x [0,0].

[jonathan2@linux-a1 lab_intro]$

Answer (score 0):

You should not call the operator function in that way, instead do this:

```
*b(i, j) = *a(j, i);
```

Comment: But it fails, it gives me the error; clang++ -std=c++1y -stdlib=libc++ -c -g -O0 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.cpp main.cpp:21:62: error: use of undeclared identifier 'erata' *b(i, j) = *a(j, i); erata ^ 1 error generated. make: *** [main.o] Error 1